# When I create unity project, it does not show 3d objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I create unity project, it does not show 3D objects:

[image]

Comment: This is like opening a pizza box from the other side and saying there is no Pepperoni in it. Rotate the camera or the Object about 180 deg and you will see it.

Comment: Investing some time in properly elaborate the question, describe exactly what you tried and what doesn't work would also help. I recommend you read this before posting questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is happening  because you can see plane/quad from one side only. There are shaders to make you see both sides if you look online.

Comment: Select the object and press `W`, you seem to be stuck in the UI (cavas) editor.

Answer (score 1):

An Quad is only visible from one side. this is also for a plane. You can solve this by rotating your camera 180 degree and look at the other side of the object. Or just place another 3D Object with multiple faces on the outside